# What is the more serious version of 'pet peeve'?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

A "pet peeve" is something minor that annoys you. What is the term for a **major** annoyance?

Comment: a "feral peeve"?

Comment: A "hot button" is something that sets you off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sense of something that is annoying specifically to me, and not to others (like a pet peeve), I would use the words **bugbear** or **bugaboo**.

The New Zealand Oxford Dictionary (2005) gives "a cause of annoyance or anger; a bête noire" as the first definition of bugbear, and "a bogey or bugbear" as the definition of bugaboo.

Comment: These are not used in the U.S. much.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> A [***thorn in my side***](http://www.allwords.com/word-thorn+in+my+side.html) : (idiom) Something that greatly annoys the subject.

Comment: Or a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2):

OK one word request- **PITA** - acronym for Pain In The Ass, a major annoyance. Best word for major annoyance **piss so(someone) off**.

Examples: You have to delete the whole entry, make changes, and add it back in anytime you want to change anything? What a big pita!

Talk to the hand... If you have any questions --> consult my middle finger. I am so pissed off. (I am in a pissy mood)